# Android Exception NameNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, exception

I don't understand why happens this exception.

In my Main activity, in the method onCreate I have this code at first:

```
   try {
        PackageInfo info = this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.mypacket", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.e("Hash", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("Hash", "Error: NameNotFoundException");
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.e("Hash", "Error: NoSuchAlgorithmException");
    }
```

The exception is NameNotFoundException, I want to solve it because I think it causes problem with the Facebook SDK.

Thank you all.

If helps, this is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myPackageName.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"
                    android:largeScreens="true"
                    android:normalScreens="true"
                    android:smallScreens="true"
                    android:xlargeScreens="true" />                     

    <permission android:name="com.myPackageName.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.myPackageName.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" /> 
    <permission android:name="com.myPackageName.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.myPackageName.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />





<uses-feature
android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
android:required="true"/>     

    <application
        android:name="@string/app_name"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>

        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.myPackageName.app" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />


        <activity
            android:name="com.myPackageName.app.SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>   



        <!-- Google Maps V2 API KEY -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="apy key" />                 
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 11):

You got your package name wrong. For safety, always use **`Context.getPackageName()`**.

```
PackageInfo info = this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your package name is **com.myPackageName.app** not *com.mypacket*.
BTW you can obtain package name by [Context#getPackageName()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getPackageName%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when you have generate hash key project and the application for which you are creating hash key are not on the some workspace / directory, so exception arises NameNotFoundException.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

It means that either you are giving wrong package name or maybe you are not sure about the package name.

Case 1. if you know about your package name, just cross check it.

Case 2. if you are not sure about the package name **(** this situation may also arise when you did some code refactoring i.e. **Rename Package )**

There are multiple approaches to fix it

1. package name is mentioned in the top of the AndroidManifest.xml

[image]

2. If it is still not resolved to get package name by

   Context.getPackageName();

or

```
Log.d();
```

In Logcat check the application column package name should be mentioned there.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you have the app already installed. If for example you were to debug your app and then test the release .apk on the same device without uninstalling the debug version. If that is the case, just uninstall and then the install should work.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall your app from your device then run it again through the android studio. It helps me